# Slide functionality with dynamic changing views in it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-view

[image]

Please have a look on this image
The whole review section will slide according to days of week saturday monday etc..
Inside values are dynamic and will come from server accordingly
there are also buttons named comment,agreeand report abuse which will update values as according to their name

How can I achieve this kind of functionality in android.
That is I am in need of sliding functionality (Left and right both)which contains a list view with dynamic changing elements. and button  on click which functionality will be there as accordingly

Please help me ASAP
thanks
Abhinav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI guys I have found the solution of my own question

See this

[android gestures](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-gestures.html)

and this link

[Switching between activities stack over flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218733/android-how-to-switch-between-activities-like-switching-desktops-in-home-app)

Thanks for visiting my question

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at ViewPager class in Android Compatibility Package.